# The difference between create Mac OS app project and iOS app project with Xcode in swiftUI？

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I want to use swiftUI to develop an application running on both iOS and Mac OS. After MAC 10.15, I can run iPad app directly on Mac. So, what's the difference between creating a Mac OS project and an IOS project?

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is the library you will use as main! Native app for iOS uses `UIKit` and for macOS uses `AppKit`. But Catalyst uses `UIKitForMac`. That is some sort of porting `UIKit` to `AppKit`. For example for mapping touch events to and clicks, or gestures to scroll (and reverse) and etc. But it is very limited comparing to the original `MapKit`. If you really need to support mac, you will ended up importing `AppKit` and use it's features alongside with the `UIKitForMac`. But catalyst will boost your development process and reduce the time it takes for the MVP and early stages of the app.